# passing parameters to filter function defined on a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

Say I have a (extremely simplified) controller defined like so:

```
 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function(scope){
     list=[1,2,3,4,5]
     scope.filterFunction = function(item, upperBound){
       if(item < upperBound){
         return(item);
       }
     }
 }]);
```

How could I pass a value for upperBound through the template?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:filterFunction">{{item}}</div>
```

I know that if you roll a dedicated filter, you can parameterize with `filterName:arg1:arg2....`

Is there any way to achieve a similiar behaviour with this approach? Or alternately, is there any way to let the controller function have access to scope?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't creating a dedicated filter you can create a function on scope that returns the filtered items.  Such as:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
    scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];
    scope.upperBound = 3;

    scope.filterFunction = function(list, upperBound) {
        var rval = [];
        for(var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            if(list[i] < upperBound)
            {
                rval.push(list[i])
            }
        }
        return rval;
    };

    // or 
    scope.filteredList = function() {
        var rval = [];
        for(var i = 0, l = scope.list.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            if(scope.list[i] < scope.upperBound)
            {
                rval.push(scope.list[i])
            }
        }
        return rval;
    };

}]);
```

and then bind to that function:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filterFunction(list,upperBound)">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filteredList()">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXEWRp2lcsXeZNScKl7X?p=preview)